# dotnet-ef migration uses wrong connection string even if it's commented out

Tags: .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to add a migration to a BETA database, but it uses the Production database even though I've changed the connection string. is there any other place it stores the connection string after performing a migration?

**Connection strings**:

```
public static class AssetsStatics
{
    // public const string ConnectionString = "Data Source=sql6010.site4now.net;Initial Catalog=DB_A4AA19_Assets;User Id=DB_A4AA19_Assets_admin;Password=**********;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;";
    public const string ConnectionString = "Data Source=sql6010.site4now.net;Initial Catalog=DB_A4AA19_AssetsBeta;User Id=DB_A4AA19_AssetsBeta_admin;Password=*******;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;";
}
```

How I add the **DBContext**:

.AddDbContext(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(AssetsStatics.ConnectionString))

**AssetsDBContext**:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnConfiguring(builder);

    builder.UseSqlServer(AssetsStatics.ConnectionString);
}
```

Even though the connection string to the production server is commented out, it uses that connection anyways.

Answer (score 0):

please clear a caching in visual studio

Also, You can remove the migration

> PM>Remove-Migration
> PM>Add-Migration

Comment: How? Can you edit your answer to include instructions?